# d3,js throbbing dots on a google map - control the outer rings to have different rates

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to give each dot - their own alarm setting. So the outer rings that are spawned can occur at different rates for different dots.

At the moment - its only taking a general value for ALL dots.

http://jsbin.com/wisiciqi/2/

```
                function callcircle(circleData, duration){

                    console.log("circleData key :: ", circleData.key);
                    console.log("duration :: ", duration);


                    var t = setInterval(function(){
                        clearInterval(t);
                        myTransition(circleData)
                    },duration);                        
                }
```

I have a function that should invoke the circle transition method for a particular duration.

Comment: Could you run this code you have on a subset of the circles?

Comment: I can run the code - but I don't understand what you mean - is it because the circles are not grouped enough?

Comment: Sorry Lars, I don't understand - if you are able to write some pseudo code - or modify the jsbin accordingly to demonstrate?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were passing in a selection. Now I don't understand your question though -- you already have custom durations for each circle, don't you?

Comment: I have tried to pass custom durations - but if you see the rings - they occur at the same rate - not at different rates....

Comment: You would also have to use that for the duration of the transition, no?

Comment: I'm not sure... is that what the problem is - I felt one controls how long the animation takes - the other is the interval at which the animation is triggered - I thought it best that just the later is altered. So a higher alarm produces MORE rings per cycle, but the rings themselves move at the same speed

Comment: Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: I would play around with the duration and delay. You should be able to get what you want that way.

Comment: I have tried this - and it seemed to be triggering different delays - but the rings would still go off at the same rate. It was as if the function did not call generations of the circles on an individual level. As if the function acted globally on all circles at the same time

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wisiciqi/7/edit - if you look at the orbs - the rings are generated at the same rate, but one should be 1/hundredth the rate than the other - so one should appear urgent, the other not so. I am getting different rates with the function function getDurationPerDot(circleData) but its as if the myTransition is triggered globally for all circles.

Comment: Still no luck trying to stabilize this - can anyone here see the problem with the transition function

Comment: Any suggestions on this - to configure the rates of the orbs ?